# The Material UI sx styles are not being applied during the build process in Next.js 14

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js14

I've made some custom modifications to the Select component. It functions correctly in development mode but isn't applied in the built version. How can I fix it?

I'm using **@mui/material": "^5.14.18**

```
import { MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";

<Select
  displayEmpty
  size={size}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
  IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
  error={error}
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      width: "1.125rem",
      color: "#9F9F9F !important",
    },
    "& .css-11u53oe-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input":
      {
        padding: ".622rem 0.875rem",
      },
    "& .css-jedpe8-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input":
      {
        padding: "0.434rem 0.875rem",
      },
    "& .css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#E8E8E8",
    },
    fontSize: "0.875rem",
    width: "100%",
    minWidth: "4rem",
  }}
  {...props}
>
  <MenuItem disabled value={"" || 0}>
    <p className="text-gray-pastel">{placeholder}</p>
  </MenuItem>
  {children}
</Select>;
```